# Reading or loading images from file synchronously in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have  bitmap images file in my computer.And I numbered images form 1 to 100.

I want to read image synchronously.

Something like:

```
for i=1:100
    % read images
    s = sprintf('C:\\images\\%d.bmp', i);  
    A[i] = imread(s);
    A[i] = double(A);
end
```

I know that this code can't work.Is there a function that perform my algorithm in MATLAB

Could you help me please?

Comment: *I know that this code can't work*, huh?

Comment: In fact I wonder there is a function that perform my algorithm

Comment: yalcin, please don't add so many additional questions (and answers) to discuss a topic. If you have something to add to a question you've asked, edit the question. If someone posts an answer that doesn't work right, leave a comment on that answer and give them a chance to update it. It's very difficult to help you when your problem is spread out over multiple questions and answers.

Comment: Ok !I pay attention to it.I apologised

Comment: yalcin, since the problem in this question is already being discussed in your other question, it would probably be best to delete this question please. I don't intend to sound mean, I just think you will get better answers by keeping things more compact and focused.

Answer (score 3):

You can use cell matrices

```
A = cell(100,1);
for i=1:100
    % read images
    s = sprintf('C:\\images\\%d.bmp', i);  
    A{i} = imread(s);
    A{i} = double(A{i});
end
```

Comment: I think you mean A{i} = double(A{i})